# Focus does not jump to another input field on mobile but does on desktop

Tags: javascript, html

This javascript work on desktop but not working on mobile. In mobile, focus does not jump to another input field.

```js
const codes = document.querySelectorAll('.otp')

codes[0].focus()

codes.forEach((code, idx) => {
    code.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
        if (e.key >= 0 && e.key <= 9) {
            codes[idx].value = ''
            setTimeout(() => codes[idx + 1].focus(), 10)
        } else if (e.key === 'Backspace') {
            setTimeout(() => codes[idx - 1].focus(), 10)
        }
    })
});
```

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
<input class="form-control login_form_control otp" type="text" maxlength="1">
<input class="form-control login_form_control otp" type="text" maxlength="1">
<input class="form-control login_form_control otp" type="text" maxlength="1">
<input class="form-control login_form_control otp" type="text" maxlength="1">
<input class="form-control login_form_control otp" type="text" maxlength="1">
<input class="form-control login_form_control otp" type="text" maxlength="1">
</div>
```

Comment: In mobile, focus is not jumb to another input field

Answer (score 0):

In mobile, after pressing enter, you need to wait more milliseconds of focusing other inputs :D You can try using 3000 ms in timeout or more to solve. In my project, it worked.